# How can I log hours that I have contributed to the project?

Tags: community

CiviCRM is contributed to by hundreds of people: users who report issues/bugs/suggestions; implementers; developers; people who take time to offer advice on this site or on [chat.civicrm.org](https://chat.civicrm.org).

It's useful for the project to have a measure of this, so we can appreciate everyone's input. As well as helping build a picture of the work that goes into improving CiviCRM over time, people who contribute enough hours can be listed on the [find an expert](https://civicrm.org/partners-contributors) page.

How can this be measured and how can I record my time?

(Note: I'm listing this here with an answer because the information was very hard to find.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can log your contributions by either:

- signing up for an account at [lab.civicrm.org](https://lab.civicrm.org/explore/groups) which is where most of the work goes on and many community discussions happen; then "joining" a project; then recording your time in a comment using a special code.

  *or*
- signing up for an account on https://civicrm.org and then using a special [work log import form](https://civicrm.org/civicrm/timetrack/import).

This process, as well as what is and isn't considered a "contribution" is set out in detail in a wiki page in the gitlab project called *Community Engagement*. The relevant page is:

https://lab.civicrm.org/community/community-engagement/wikis/Tracking-Contributions